# Unity2D shake and lagging problem while my character is moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Profiler.BeginSample ("MyPieceOfCode");

        if (npc.GetComponent<textAnimation>().textFinished)
        { 
            attacking();
            getFire();
            slashAnim();
            getDamage();
        }
        //Profiler.EndSample ();
    }
    void Update()
    {
        cameraSystem();
        if (!getDamaged && !firehit)
        {
            moving();
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("running", false);
        }
    }

void moving()
    {
        if ((_right.isRight || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) && !isDeath)
        {
            walkingright=true;
            spr.flipX = false;
            anim.SetBool("running", true);
            /*if(isGround){
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y-0.045f,transform.position.z);
            }*/
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * playerSpeed);
            if (!walking.isPlaying && isGround)
            {
                walking.Play();
            }
            if (!foodstep.isPlaying && onStone)
            {
                foodstep.Play();
            }

        }
        else if ((_left.isLeft || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) && !isDeath)
        {
            walkingright=false;
            spr.flipX = true;
            anim.SetBool("running", true);
            /*if(isGround)
            {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y-0.045f,transform.position.z);
            }*/
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * playerSpeed);
            if (!walking.isPlaying && isGround)
            {
                walking.Play();
            }
            if (!foodstep.isPlaying && onStone)
            {
                foodstep.Play();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            _walking=false;
            anim.SetBool("running", false);
            walking.Stop();
            foodstep.Stop();
        }
        if (isGround)
        {
            weaponR.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = true;
            weaponL.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            weaponR.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = false;
            weaponL.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = false;
        }
        if ((isJump.jmp || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) && !isDeath && isGround)
        {
            rgd.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 2.750f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jumpAudio.Play();
            isGround = false;

        }
        if (health.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x >= 0 && hit)
        {
            health.rectTransform.sizeDelta -= new Vector2(damage, 0);
            hit = false;
        }
    }

void cameraSystem()
    {

        float distance = Vector2.Distance(cam.transform.position, transform.position);
        Vector2 direction = transform.position - cam.transform.position;
        if (distance > .8f && direction.x > 0)
        {   _walking=true;
            cam.transform.Translate(Vector2.right * playerSpeed);
            _direction=1;
        }
        else if (distance > .8f && direction.x < 0)
        {   _walking=true;
            cam.transform.Translate(Vector2.left * playerSpeed);
            _direction=-1;
        }
        else{
            _walking=false;
        }
    }
```

here is another code style i've tried

```
void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Profiler.BeginSample ("MyPieceOfCode");
        cameraSystem();
        if (npc.GetComponent<textAnimation>().textFinished)
        {
            if(!getDamaged && !firehit)
            {
                moving();
            }
            else
            {
                anim.SetBool("running", false);
            }
            attacking();
            getFire();
            slashAnim();
            getDamage();
        }
        //Profiler.EndSample ();
    }
    void moving()
    {
        if ((_right.isRight || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) && !isDeath)
        {
            walkingright=true;
            spr.flipX = false;
            anim.SetBool("running", true);
            if(isGround){
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y-0.045f,transform.position.z);
            }
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * 1.75f);
            if (!walking.isPlaying && isGround)
            {
                walking.Play();
            }
            if (!foodstep.isPlaying && onStone)
            {
                foodstep.Play();
            }

        }
        else if ((_left.isLeft || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) && !isDeath)
        {
            walkingright=false;
            spr.flipX = true;
            anim.SetBool("running", true);
            if(isGround)
            {
            transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x,transform.position.y-0.045f,transform.position.z);
            }
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * 1.75f);
            if (!walking.isPlaying && isGround)
            {
                walking.Play();
            }
            if (!foodstep.isPlaying && onStone)
            {
                foodstep.Play();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            _walking=false;
            anim.SetBool("running", false);
            walking.Stop();
            foodstep.Stop();
        }
        if (isGround)
        {
            weaponR.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = true;
            weaponL.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            weaponR.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = false;
            weaponL.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().simulated = false;
        }
        if ((isJump.jmp || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) && !isDeath && isGround)
        {
            rgd.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 2.750f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            jumpAudio.Play();
            isGround = false;

        }
        if (health.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x >= 0 && hit)
        {
            health.rectTransform.sizeDelta -= new Vector2(damage, 0);
            hit = false;
        }
    }
```

Whenever i attempt to move my character,i see always there is annoying shaking and lagging in my 2D platformer game while fps is above 90.
İ've been searching for 5 hours,but i couldn't where my problem is.
is it may bug at kernel of UnityEngine ? Because i noticed there are a lot of people  facind exacltly this problem.
İ want to smooth movement,like in other 2D indie platformer games.
Here is my game screen: https://pasteboard.co/Is3eM42.gif
Here is my video: https://streamable.com/gi78h
Look at mountain,do you see drops ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity Ball Shaking as it moves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37383833/unity-ball-shaking-as-it-moves)

Comment: it didn't solved my problem

Comment: https://streamable.com/gi78h

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
rgd.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 2.750f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

with

```
rgd.velocity = Vector2.up * 2.75;
```